# Python Flask External API Connection Refused

Tags: python, flask

I have a python Flask app hosted on GoDaddy that I access through cPanel. This app works on my computer with no errors. I can make the api calls and get the data as it should. When I migrate everything to cPanel I get a connection refused error. If I add an API call that doesn't require a secondary external api call I get no error (A simple return "Hello World")

I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing that I'm supposed to add to my code or if this is GoDaddy blocking me from making connections maybe?

I've been all over github, stackoverflow, and many other sites looking for an answer. Does anyone have knowledge or advice on how I can either fix or better diagnose my issue?

Error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='orders.getkrakn.biz', port=40443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cgi-bin/tnet/GenerateToken.p (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x2b757f60b220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Here is KraknApi.py:

(Please note: I know it's technically not minimal reproducible as I left out my username and password. However, I have no ability to easily change those.)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests
import json
import logging


logging.basicConfig(filename='record.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

#Generate token from SW
def getToken():
    #API Call
    tokenUrl = 'https://orders.getkrakn.biz:40443/cgi-bin/tnet/GenerateToken.p'
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    data= '{"Authorization":[{"username":[username],"password":[password]}]}'
    uriResponse = requests.get(tokenUrl,headers=headers,data=data)
    
    #Parsing Token Data to get Token
    tokenData = json.loads(uriResponse.text)
    token = tokenData['wToken'][0]['TOKEN']
    
    #Send Token
    return token


# API Path Name
@app.route('/api/CustomerMaster', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
#Path Function
def get_custMaster():
    #Getting Params
    hCo = request.args.get('hCo')
    hCust = request.args.get('hCustomer')
    hSalesrep = request.args.get('hSalesrep')
    
    #NullCheck
    if hCust==None:
        hCust=''
    elif hSalesrep==None:
        hSalesrep=''
    
    
    #Generate Token from SW
    token = getToken()

    #API Call
    url = 'https://orders.getkrakn.biz:40443/cgi-bin/tnet/CustomerMaster.p' + '?hCo=' + hCo + '&hCustomer=' + hCust + '&hSalesrep=' + hSalesrep + '&hToken=' + token
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    uriResponse = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

    # Return the JSON response
    return jsonify(uriResponse.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=80)
```